# SwipeRefresh gets stuck on the 3rd spin (blue, green, orange)

Tags: android, android-animation, swiperefreshlayout

Has anyone encountered the issue of the pull down fresh animation getting stuck on the third color? I'm not getting a minimum of 3 circles (O), I get 2.5 with the final one being resembling the letter "C".The first two colors perform a 360, and the last color gets stuck at 180 sit there for a few seconds then goes away and the data/screen refreshes. When I comment out refreshListView() the circle loops infinitely. I'm not sure if this matters, but my circle gets stuck on the color orange, even though I'm not using that color specifically in my code.

Any ideas?

Refresh code//

```
swipeLayout = (SwipeRefreshLayout) findViewById(R.id.swipe_container);
swipeLayout.setColorSchemeResources(android.R.color.holo_green_light, android.R.color.holo_blue_light, android.R.color.holo_green_light);

swipeLayout.setOnRefreshListener(new SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener() {
    @Override
    public void onRefresh() {
        swipeLayout.setRefreshing(true);
        Log.d("Swipe", "Refreshing Number");
        ( new Handler()).postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                Connectivity check = new Connectivity(getApplicationContext());
                if (!(check.isConnectingToInternet())) {
                    check.showAlertDialog(Summary.this, "No internet connection", "Noo interweb detected." + " Please check your connection.", false);
                }
                else {
                    refreshListView(); //A lot is happening in this method. I don't mind the fact that it takes a little bit to complete, but I do not like that the animation freezes.
                }
            }
        }, 3000);
    }
});
```

Comment: I was able to determine that the infinite loop animation is a result of failing to set set.Refreshing to false.

Answer (score 0):

I eventually broke down, and used an Asynctask to resolve this.